# Get Future<double> from async function in a RangeSlider

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, future, rangeslider

I got a RangeSlider where I get my max: from a async function, the RangeSlider is in a FutureBuilder.
The Error is "Future" is not a subtype of "double" normally i just but await there but that doesnt work in my Widget FutureBuilder.

```
RangeSlider(
values: _currentRangeValues,
min: 0,
max: a = // I tried double.parse(snapshot.data), and I tried to double.parse(asyncfct()),                
divisions: 10,
labels: RangeLabels(
_currentRangeValues.start.round().toString(),
_currentRangeValues.end.round().toString(),),
onChanged: (RangeValues values) {
setState(() {
_currentRangeValues = values;});})
```

Comment: did you try doing this double.parse(await asyncfct())

Comment: yeah, but you cannot use await in FutureBuilder

Comment: Widget build(BuildContext context) 
thats my Widget but I cannot make it asynchronous for my purpose

Comment: can you show code for asyncfct() method, I think you are not returning a double value in this function.

Comment: Ayo thanks for your help I was just a little dumb